# HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-ce3xxx - RTL8821CE - network not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

After installing RTL8821CE-dkms, WiFi still does not seem to be working. Any help?

Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

```
$ apt-cache search rtl8821ce
rtl8821ce-dkms - DKMS source for the Realtek 8821C PCIe WiFi driver
```

Comment: Secure Boot enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Secure Boot is disabled and then put in the command

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Once it is done with the install restart your computer and you should have wifi.

if it is truly already installed, replace the install with reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the kernel module and restarting worked for me:

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```